# Django: why does NOT this give a syntax error?

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE**
This question has been marked as duplicate. The linked question answers my question partially. I have two questions and it answers one.

**ORIGINAL**

I am new to Django.

I just by mistake put a space between this query and realized that it still works when I would expect it to give an error.

```
ClinicDoctorDayShift.objects.filter(clinic_doctor__doctor_id = doctor_id).all() .order_by('day_shift__time')
```

There is a space between `all()` and `.order_by`.

Why doesn't it raise an error? the `order_by` still works. WHY?

And one more thing. what is difference between

```
ClinicDoctorDayShift.objects.filter(clinic_doctor__doctor_id = doctor_id)
```

and

```
ClinicDoctorDayShift.objects.filter(clinic_doctor__doctor_id = doctor_id).all()
```

One is without `all()`. They work same way, apparently, when I use them in my template.

Thank you

Comment: `all()` only returns all objects that the query would return.